# SyntaxError in Localhost:8000 Python Django

Tags: django, syntax-error

So I am following a Django tutorial and I have the following directory for a project:

```
demo/
    demo/
        apps/
            ventas/
                __init__.py
                admin.py
                models.py
                tests.py
                views.py
            __init.py
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
 manage
```

And under admin.py I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from demo.apps.ventas.models import cliente.producto

# Register the ventas models
admin.site.register(cliente)
admin.site.register(producto)
```

And from models.py,

```
from django.db import models

class cliente(models.Model):
    nombre      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    apellido    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status      = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class producto(models.Model):
    nombre      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    status      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

But when I run `python manage.py runserver` from Django_tutorial2/demo, I received the 
SyntaxErrro in admin.py, line 2 in localhost:8000. It  still worked before I added the ventas folder.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

`from demo.apps.ventas.models import cliente, producto`

This will import the class cliente and the class producto.

Answer (score 0):

```
from demo.apps.ventas.models import cliente.producto
```

replace it with:

```
from demo.apps.ventas.models import cliente, producto
```